# PHP OOP best practice: Load different version of class function depending on condition

Tags: php, oop

I'm building a payment gateway class that will work with different gateways. First I load the standard class with shared functionality. Then I want to load different versions of functions depending on which gateway is used. The var deciding which version should be used is the `$gatewayCode` var, which in this case could have values `paypal` or `stripe`, which then would load `Gateway.PayPal.php` or `Gateway.Stripe.php`.

I want to be able to run the gateway-specific functions `setupRedirect()` and `receivePayment()`, and let the gateway-specific classes do the magic. How do I implement this?

**index.php**

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/classes/Gateway.php');

$gatewayCode = 'paypal';
$payType = 'booking';
$bookingId = 50;
$siteLangCode = 'es';

$gateway = new Gateway($gatewayCode, $payType, $bookingId, $siteLangCode);
```

**Gateway.php**

```
class Gateway {
    //Gateway config
    private $authVars;
    private $needsInit; //Needs init before redirecting
    private $doesRedirect; //Gateway redirects as opposed to staying on the page
    
    //Payment info
    private $currencyCode;
    
    //Pay item info
    private $payItemType; //'booking' or 'ttInvoice'
    private $payItemId; //Booking id or invoice id
    private $payItem;
    
    //Misc
    private $mysqli_tt;
    private $mysqli_biz;
    private $lang;
    
    //URLs
    private $bookingUrl;
    private $cancelUrl;
    
    private $embedded; //using iframes or not
    
    public function __construct ($gatewayCode, $payItemType, $payItemId, $siteLangCode) {
        //Fetch gateway config
    }
    
    public function getPayItemDesc() { //Get short desc str for what is being paid
        //Fetch item desc
    }
    
    private function getPayItemData($varName) {
        //Fetch some data of item
    }
    
    private function getPayAmt() {
        //Return payment amount
    }
}
```

**Gateway.PayPal.php**

```
class PayPal extends Gateway {
    public function setupRedirect() {
        //Gateway-specific functionality here
    }
    
    public function receivePayment() {
        //Gateway-specific functionality here
    }
}
```

**Gateway.Stripe.php**

```
class Stripe extends Gateway {
    public function setupRedirect() {
        //Gateway-specific functionality here
    }
    
    public function receivePayment() {
        //Gateway-specific functionality here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want is an abstract class https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: ...and maybe you could read about GoF design patterns. At least one of them works great here

Comment: Load all classes and use upcasting method.